# Getting drawing image from canvas to flask

Tags: javascript, python, machine-learning, flask, canvas

I'm writing a small Flask app to recognize handwritten digits (0-9). I wrote almost all the elements (machine learning model, web app, etc.) but I'm having a problem capturing an image (drawn using Canvas) like:

[image: enter screen from app here]

I would like to get the image and save it to a temp file. I know Python but I've never used JavaScript, which is necessary for using Canvas.

HTML:

```
<form method="post"  action="{{url_for('main.image')}}">
    <button name="img" onclick="drawDataURIOnCanvas();">Get png</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function InitThis() {
        ....
    }

 function Draw(x, y, isDown) {
        ....

 function drawDataURIOnCanvas() {

      var element = document.createElement('a');
      element.setAttribute('href',  document.getElementById('Canvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
      element.setAttribute('download', 'chart.jpeg');
      element.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(element);
      element.click();

    }
```

Function `drawDataURIOnCanvas()` saves the image using *browser save manager*, but I would like to save it to temp files and use the image later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the browser doesn't allow you to programmatically save files to a user's filesystem due to security concerns. Since this is going to a Flask application you should instead read the image information from the `<canvas>` tag and send the image information directly to the app via XHR/AJAX or a standard `<form>`. This is assuming that you are writing it temporarily so that Flask can read it from disk.

If you absolutely have to make this work with temp files then you can get around this limitation by writing browser plugins/extensions, though in the case of chrome you will likely need the combination of both an extension and an app to get the necessary file access.

Comment: I is not necessary to download an image. I just need the image just for recognize it by ML model, so I just need "kind of information about image". Do you know how to read that information using <form> ?

Comment: You're already reading it with `document.getElementById('Canvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg'))`. You can take this and [set the value attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) on an `<input>` element inside of a `<form>` to send the data to your application. You will need an endpoint in Flask to handle this if you don't have one already. Here is an article you may find helpful: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-machine-learning-as-a-rails-developer-739cc57ea01c